# Swift/Obtaining a Device Token in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, devicetoken

I'm brand new to iOS development and I'm trying to figure out how to obtain a device token for iOS. I've been following the documentation as written for Swift in listing 4-1 here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/HandlingRemoteNotifications.html

On this line: `self.configureUserInteractions()` (or any line referencing "self"), I'm receiving an error which says: Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'configureUserInteractions'. I'm thinking maybe I'm missing an import statement in my AppDelegate.swift file, but I cant find any information on this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.configureUserInteractions()` is a method that Apple uses an example. Completely unnecessary to implement. 
`func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)` is all you need to get the device token.

Answer (score 0):

The method `configureUserInteractions` should be a custom method of your `AppDelegate`, so you have to implement it first, but
if you just need to get a remote notification token (for Push Notifications) simply implement `UIApplicationDelegate` this protocol method in your `AppDelegate` class:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    print(deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})) // prints deviceToken
}
```